# Full word cursor movement in DBVisualizer script editor

Tags: dbvisualizer

I have been unable to find how to do full-word cursor movement in the DBVisualizer script editor. 
 The normal `macos` commands of `ctl-[left/right]arrow` and `Option-[left/right]arrow` do not work. The `Command-[left/right]arrow` does something different: it moves to beginning or end of entire line instead of the current word.    Presently I am making do with single character at a time cursor movements. This is slow on a long sql line.   Examining the available shortcuts there are none mentioned for intra-line/horizontal cursor movement but only vertical:

[image]

Does anyone know what magic key combinations do this fundamental cursor movement?

Comment: Please try Option+left/right arrow to move to previous or next word. I assume you are using the macOS key binding map in Tools->Tool Properties under the Key Bindings category?

Comment: Question actually (tried to) mention that has already been attempted:  "`Option-[left/right]arrow do not work.`"

Comment: I suggest you open a support ticket using Help->Contact Support in DbVisualizer so that we can investigate

Comment: @roger  OK I just posted the issue as you suggested. Thx for your interest!   Ticket id: #36099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbVisualizer` uses the term "insertion point" for this concept:

[image]